# Pre-deploying Kubernetes loadbalancer with terraform on DigitalOcean?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, terraform, digital-ocean

I'm learning about creating a k8s cluster on DO using terraform, I've been trying to take the `ID` of the single K8s node I've created, and reference it from the loadbalancer.

The main reasoning for this is so that I can declare the FQDN in the `.tf` file.

First, here is the cluster declaration:

```
variable "digitalocean_token" {}

provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "${var.digitalocean_token}"
}

resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "foo" {
  name    = "foo"
  region  = "nyc1"
  version = "1.12.1-do.2"

  node_pool {
    name       = "woker-pool"
    size       = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
    node_count = 1
  }
}
```

And here is the load balancer declaration:

```
resource "digitalocean_loadbalancer" "foo" {
  name = "k8s-lb.nyc1"
  region = "nyc1"

  forwarding_rule {
    entry_port = 80
    entry_protocol = "http"

    target_port     = 80
    target_protocol = "http"
  }
  droplet_ids = ["${digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.foo.node_pool.0.id}"]
}

output "loadbalancer_ip" {
  value = "${digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo.ip}"
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "terraform" {
  domain = "example.com" # "${digitalocean_domain.example.name}"
  type   = "A"
  name   = "terraform"
  value  =  "${digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo.ip}"
}

# Output the FQDN for the record
output "fqdn" {
  value = "${digitalocean_record.terraform.fqdn}"
}
```

I'm guessing that maybe the `digitalocean_loadbalancer` resources is only setup to work with individual droplets?

---

Here are the output errors: when I run `terraform apply`:

```
* output.loadbalancer_ip: Resource 'digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo' not found for variable 'digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo.ip'

* digitalocean_record.terraform: Resource 'digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo' not found for variable 'digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo.ip'

* digitalocean_loadbalancer.foo: droplet_ids.0: cannot parse '' as int: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "d4292e64-9c0a-4afb-83fc-83f239bcb4af": invalid syntax
```

---

Pt. 2

I added a `digitalocean_droplet` resource, to see what kind of id was passed to the load balancer.

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  name      = "web-1"
  size      = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  image     = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  region    = "nyc1"
}
```

`digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.foo.node_pool.0.id = '6ae6a787-d837-4e78-a915-cb52155f66fe'`

`digitalocean_droplet.web.id = 132533158`

Comment: Those error messages are referencing `k8s-foo` resource names, which are absent from your supplied config. Please update the config to match what is causing those errors.

Comment: Fixed that typo and added some additional research items.

Answer (score 4):

So, the `digitalocean_loadbalancer` resource has an optional `droplet_tag` argument, which can be used to supply a common tag given to the created nodes/droplets.

However, when declaring a load-balancer inside kubernetes, a new one will still be created. So for now at least, it would appear that defining the domain/CNAME record with terraform isn't possible on digitalocean

Comment: DO documentation seems to support this claim, although it does not explicitly talk about the terraform provider: "Load balancers created in the control panel or via the API cannot be used by your Kubernetes clusters." https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/add-load-balancers/

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong attribute reference for your load balancer droplet ids.

`droplet_ids = ["${digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.foo.node_pool.0.id}"]`

This will use the `node_pool` id linked [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#id-1)

What you actually need to do is use the `node_pool` *nodes* id, which is referenced [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#id-2)

```
droplet_ids = "${digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.foo.node_pool.0.nodes}"
```

The next problem you're going to have is that this returns a list of maps, and you'll need to build a list of ids from that. I'm not currently sure how to solve that, I'm afraid, but this should move you along hopefully.

It seems from your answer however, that what you want to do is update DNS for your loadbalancer.

You can do this [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns) using the [digitalocean provider](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/digitalocean.md)

Simply deploy this as a pod, specifying the required configuration, and ensure that the arg `--source=service` is set.

If you want to go a step further, and allow updating DNS with specific hostname, deploy an ingress controller like nginx-ingress and specify ingresses for your applications. The external-dns deployment (if you set `--source=ingress`) will the hostname from your ingress and update DNS for you.

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered using a common droplet tag as the simplest way of doing this, however, k8s has no relationship with the LB declared here.

Comment: It seems your original question didn't include what you were actually trying to do - which seems to be update DNS for an app deployed with a loadbalancer, right? I've updated my answer to include that info.